# wrap paragraph in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to wrap a paragraph. I have tried the following in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap [w vipga
```

But there are two problems:

1. It does not work for me (even though the key sequence works for me when I type it manually).
2. I would like my cursor position to stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to reformat is `gq`, not `ga` (you may have remapped that, but then would need to use `:nmap` for the mappings to apply).

To maintain the cursor position (as much as possible, as the reformat may make the current position invalid), you can set a mark and then jump back to it. Ergo:

```
:nnoremap [w m`vipgqg``
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Could you please give an example of where the current position becomes invalid? I would be quite curious to learn more about this.

Comment: Well, actually I had in mind the cursor being on a column larger than `'textwidth'`, and the reformatting putting that position into the second line, but actually Vim handles this. There might be other situations, though.